# Clinch with one opponent's arm inside

Tags: muay-thai, grappling

I'd like to know if this unorthodox clinch technique is advisable. Watching amateur muay Thai fights, I see this pattern emerging, but it tends to be rare in professional fights. I don't know why. In my humble opinion, it's an effective technique, because as an arm triangle choke, the opponent has more problems to breath and to adjust its body to a better position. What do you think?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a classical head triangle every minimally capable grappler should know.

It is very effective, yes, but in order to be applicable, you need to have an opponent with broken posture.

If you are not sure that you either have more strength in you or have already broken their posture to their back this may result to your own posture being broken to your back and because the grip so closely links the bodies together, giving your opponent a good chance to take you down.

The best point when to apply it is when you got an opponent who leans into and/or turns the whole body in a punch, breaking their own balance. Then, you can easily catch the arm with a head triangle and change angles to completely break their posture: you got both enough time and an instable opponent to do so. You won't see this kind of mistake much on a professional level.

Thus, the reason you don't see this as much in professional fights *in the standing position* is that people are better at assessing risks and maintaining posture so that it just is too risky for them to do so most of the times and they won't even try. *On the ground* it is more common but at the same time is not seen that often because it is so devastating when applied from the top that the fighters are very aware of the move and try hard to avoid being caught in it.